# Imagemagick unexpected end of file sporadically

Tags: bash, imagemagick, imagemagick-convert, entropy

I'm trying to use Imagemagick in a script to do some studying on file entropy visualization.

I have the following bash script:

```
convert -size 2896x2896 mono:$1 -crop 100x100+0+0 -scale 300x300 data-mono-$1.png
convert -size 1024x1024 -depth 8 gray:$1 -scale 300x300 data-gray-$1.png
```

I'm not entirely fluent in imagemagick, as I found this script online, and it's worked for me on some files.

My issue is that it works about 70% of the time.

I'll take my /var/log/syslog file as a raw data input (a copy of the file), and sometimes it works, and sometimes it doesn't.  I'm guessing it has something to do with the length of the file, and the sizes I'm inputting (possibly the depth).

The exact error I'm getting when it doesn't work at all is:

```
convert-im6.q16: unexpected end-of-file `exampleData.raw': No such file or directory @ error/gray.c/ReadGRAYImage/237.
convert-im6.q16: no images defined `data-gray-exampleData.raw.png' @ error/convert.c/ConvertImageCommand/3258.
```

Sometimes the mono line works, and sometimes they both work, but it's pretty rare for the gray line to work.

Comment: Check that you have plenty of space in your /tmp directory. Remove any large files esp those related to ImageMagick in the name.

Comment: There appear to be no issues in `/tmp`.  Pretty empty.

Comment: Is it inconsistent per file?

Comment: What is your IM version and platform? What type of file is your input and your output?  Check the versions of the relevant delegates for those file formats and update if possible as well as update IM.

Comment: Ubuntu 20.04, ImageMagick 6.9.10-23 Q16

Answer (score 2):

I see two things you can do to try to alleviate the pain:

- quote your shell variables to avoid problems with filenames with spaces
- calculate your expected file size

---

So, firstly the quoting. If your filename in `$1` is `"sample data"`, the following command:

```
convert -size 2896x2896 mono:$1 data-mono-$1.png
```

will become:

```
convert -size 2896x2896 mono:sample data data-mono-sample data.png
```

which will make **ImageMagick** look for a mono file called `"sample"` which it won't find and a command parameter called `data` which it won't know either so that will lead to errors. In short, you should always double quote shell variables. So try using:

```
convert -size 2896x2896 "mono:$1" -crop 100x100+0+0 -scale 300x300 "data-mono-$1.png"
convert -size 1024x1024 -depth 8 "gray:$1" -scale 300x300 "data-gray-$1.png"
```

---

As regards the second plan of attack, the error you mention means that there was insufficient data in the file vis-à-vis what **ImageMagick** was expecting. So, you could pre-calculate the expected size and compare with the actual size and either not run **ImageMagick** or put the file to one side for checking. So, in the easier second case, if your image is 1024px wide by 1024px tall and 8-bit/pixel greyscale, you could do:

```
# width and height
W=1024
H=1024
# expected and actual size, in bytes
exp=$((W*H))
act=$(wc -c < "$1")

if [ $exp -ne $act ] ; then
   report error and save offending file
else
   convert -size ${W}x${H} -depth 8 "gray:$1" -scale 300x300 "data-gray-$1.png"
fi
```

And in the case of the mono file, you need to round up to the nearest whole number of bytes:

```
# width and height
W=2896
H=2896
# expected and actual size, in bytes
exp=$(( (W*H+7)/8 ))
act=$(wc -c < "$1")

if [ $exp -ne $act ] ; then
   report error and save offending file
else
   convert -size ${W}x${H} "mono:$1" -crop 100x100+0+0 -scale 300x300 "data-mono-$1.png"
fi
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  I think some of my confusion stems from the fact that the mono convert works no matter what the file size is going in.  And the gray seems to fail most of the time (It has worked before, but I haven't been able to duplicate a success recently).  It's almost as if the size of the file doesn't matter with these commands.  I still haven't resolved the issue since the above code will result in `$exp` and `$act` only being the same in very rare situations.  I'm not sure that they are even supposed to be the same.

Answer (score 1):

The issue appears if the raw input file (in `MONO` or `GRAY` [format](https://imagemagick.org/script/formats.php#supported)) does not match the input size (e.g. `-size 1024x1024`). For example, the input file with the `GRAY` format should have 1024x1024=1048576 bytes assuming a depth of 8-bit.

If you don't want to use the whole file to visualize the entropy, you can trim the file with `head -c 1048576 bigfile > f.gray`. Another option is to pass the file to stdin which will not trigger an unexpected end-of-file error. You can achieve this by replacing the file name with `-` (e.g. `cat bigfile | convert -size 1024x1024 -depth 8 gray:-`).